# How to parse XML with namespaces in tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an xml link (http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries) with the following data:

```xml
<wb:countries xmlns:wb="http://www.worldbank.org" page="1" pages="6" per_page="50" total="299">
<wb:country id="ABW">
<wb:iso2Code>AW</wb:iso2Code>
<wb:name>Aruba</wb:name>
<wb:region id="LCN" iso2code="ZJ">Latin America & Caribbean </wb:region>
<wb:adminregion id="" iso2code=""/>
<wb:incomeLevel id="HIC" iso2code="XD">High income</wb:incomeLevel>
<wb:lendingType id="LNX" iso2code="XX">Not classified</wb:lendingType>
<wb:capitalCity>Oranjestad</wb:capitalCity>
<wb:longitude>-70.0167</wb:longitude>
<wb:latitude>12.5167</wb:latitude>
</wb:country>
<wb:country id="AFE">
<wb:iso2Code>ZH</wb:iso2Code>
<wb:name>Africa Eastern and Southern</wb:name>
<wb:region id="NA" iso2code="NA">Aggregates</wb:region>
<wb:adminregion id="" iso2code=""/>
<wb:incomeLevel id="NA" iso2code="NA">Aggregates</wb:incomeLevel>
<wb:lendingType id="" iso2code="">Aggregates</wb:lendingType>
<wb:capitalCity/>
<wb:longitude/>
<wb:latitude/>
</wb:country>
</wb:countries>
```

I tried to parse the incomeLevel but it returns (None)
how to reach the text (ex: High income) in the xml text using BeautifulSoup?
I tried this code but it does not work as it should!

```py
import requests
#import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
countries= soup.findAll('wb:country')
for country in countries:
    name = country.find("wb:name").text
    code = country.find('wb:iso2code').text
    incomeLevel = country.find('wb:incomeLevel', {"iso2code":"XD"})
    print(f"{name}, {code}, {incomeLevel}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the question. I think you have a few things wrong in the code. This will help you rectify your errors.

1. Instead of `findAll` you should use the new method i.e. `find_all` from the bs4 API. Please refer this link https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names
2. In the second argument of `BeautifulSoup` please specify "lxml-xml" or simply "xml" as it instructs beautifulsoup to generate a XML document otherwise it'll just generate a plain HTML document and in your question you wish to parse and extract stuff from a XML document. Please refer the following link https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Please refer the following code snippet :)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
countries = soup.find_all('wb:country')
for country in countries:
    name = country.find('wb:name').text
    code = country.find('wb:iso2Code').text
    income_level = country.find('wb:incomeLevel').text
    print(f'Name: {name} Code: {code} Income Level: {income_level}')
```

Comment: There is no need to decode using "utf-8-sig". Why do you say that this is the most important point?

Comment: Try to use the response content as is. I can guarantee it won't be parsed. I've tried it out :)

Comment: I have also tried it out and `.decode('utf-8-sig')` was not needed.

Comment: 'ï»¿<?xml version="1.0". if you make a request to the url and check the text you see a wierd character which suggests it is utf-8-sig. I guess you are right, it's not needed. bs4 auto detects the encoding somehow. But it's better to be explicit about it, wouldn't result in any surprises down the line :)

Comment: The weird characters are the Byte Order Mark. It can be present in an UTF-8 file, but that is not something that you should have to worry about. Byte order has no meaning in UTF-8. Why would there be surprises down the line?

Comment: You are right. I thought i needed to decode it in utf-8-sig because when i was trying to pass response.text to the `BeautifulSoup` object it turned out to be empty. Hence i thought those characters needs to be removed and a direct way to do that is `response.content.decode("utf-8-sig")` but yeah `response.content` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

The parser has problems to parse the `BeautifulSoup` object with xml namespaces well, cause it is created as HTML, thats why you get a `None` and you won't get the text while you not adding `.text` method. So it is a combination of both.

#### How to achieve?

Pass `xml` as parser to `BeautifulSoup` to handle namespaces properly and as valid xml not as html:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
```

Add the `.text` to your result:

```
incomeLevel = country.find('incomeLevel').text
```

If you like to get only the countries with incomeLevel and iso2code="XD", change your selector and use `css selectors` instead of `find_all()`:

```
countries = soup.select('country:has(incomeLevel[iso2code="XD"])')
for country in countries:
    name = country.find("name").text
    code = country.find('iso2Code').text
    incomeLevel = country.find('incomeLevel').text
    print(f"{name}, {code}, {incomeLevel}")
```

**NOTE:** *xml parser works case sensitive `find('iso2code')` won't work, you have to change to `find('iso2Code')`*

#### Example

**NOTE:** *In new code better use actually syntax `find_all()` instead of outdated `findAll()`*

```
import requests
#import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
countries= soup.find_all('country')
for country in countries:
    name = country.find("name").text
    code = country.find('iso2Code').text
    incomeLevel = country.find('incomeLevel').text
    print(f"{name}, {code}, {incomeLevel}")
```

#### Output

```
Aruba, AW, High income
Africa Eastern and Southern, ZH, Aggregates
Afghanistan, AF, Low income
Africa, A9, Aggregates
Africa Western and Central, ZI, Aggregates
Angola, AO, Lower middle income
Albania, AL, Upper middle income
Andorra, AD, High income
Arab World, 1A, Aggregates
United Arab Emirates, AE, High income
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use the **ElementTree** class from the xml module, and especially take into account the namespace:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

ns = {'wb': 'http://www.worldbank.org'}

countries = ET.parse('input.xml').getroot()

for country in countries.findall('wb:country', namespaces=ns):
    name = country.find("wb:name", namespaces=ns).text
    code = country.find('wb:iso2Code', namespaces=ns).text
    
    incomeLevel = None
    for x in country.findall('wb:incomeLevel', namespaces=ns):
        if x.get('iso2code') == 'XD':
            incomeLevel = x.text
            break
    
    print(f"{name}, {code}, {incomeLevel}")
```

When I run that on the sample you provided, **input.xml**, I get:

```
Aruba, AW, High income
Africa Eastern and Southern, ZH, None
```